# Program not responding after Button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I know it ain't pretty but i am still rather new at programming. 
After i input the n1, n2 and n3 and press calculate the form gets an
"Program not responding"

it does so both in Debug and Release mode and i have no visible error messages.Anyone who can help me? it is for an assignment due tomorrow, and right now i cannot see a fix, so any help is much appreciated.

If you need a copy of the code to check, please send me a pm.

With kind regards. Mathias

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace I3_REVISI
{
    public partial class Newton : Form
{
    public static double n1, n2, n3, x_NEWTON, Initialization, x1, approx1, approx2, approx3, approx4, approx5, approx6;
    public Newton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox6.Text = "";
        textBox10.Text = "";
        textBox13.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        Newton1.Text = "";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
        n2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text);
        n3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text);
        // Initialization If value is positive the start value is xinitialization -1 f(0) = xinitialization-1

        for (x_NEWTON = 0; x1 >= 0; x_NEWTON++)
        {
            x1 = n1 * Math.Pow(x_NEWTON, 2) + n2 * x_NEWTON + n3;
            Initialization = x1 - 1;
        }

        // Formula:   x1 = x0 - ( f(x0) / f'(x0) )
            approx1 = Initialization - ((n1*Math.Pow(Initialization,2)+n2*Initialization+n3) / (n1*2*Initialization-n2));
        approx2 = approx1 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx1, 2) + n2 * approx1 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx1 - n2));
        approx3 = approx2 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx2, 2) + n2 * approx2 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx2 - n2));
        approx4 = approx3 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx3, 2) + n2 * approx3 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx3 - n2));
        approx5 = approx4 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx4, 2) + n2 * approx4 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx4 - n2));
        approx6 = approx5 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx5, 2) + n2 * approx5 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx5 - n2));

        Newton1.Text = ("" + approx6);

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Suspecting that for loop is running indefinitely. Use try catch for exception. It might throw stack overflow exception. x1 >= 0;

Comment: Your for loop continues while `x1 >= 0`, is this ever false? If not, your loop will never end. I recommend taking a look at [using the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: How would that look like using try catch?

Comment: @CodeConstruct it would never throw a StackOverflowException. -- Mathias a try/catch wouldn't do anything here.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on using the debugger in Visual Studio](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/vs-get-started/debugging).

Comment: @CodeConstruct also, `StackOverflowException` can't be catched in `try/catch` block.

Comment: @vasily.sib  and john apologies . Thanks

Comment: You were right, it was the For loop.. But i don't understand why it continues to run, the break condition of bigger than 0 should be reached.

Any suggestions on how to build it instead?

Comment: "the break condition of bigger than 0 should be reached" - that isn't a break condition, it's a continuation condition. See [C# `for` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#the-condition-section)

Comment: As for a suggestion: if you thought that it was a break condition, just reverse the logic to make it correct: `i >= 0` becomes `i < 0`.

Comment: Try initialising xnewton to 1

Comment: USe the powerful Debugger and breakpoints.

Comment: If this is an assigment for tomorrow, than i suggest getting started with debugging. Putting your code here wont help you. You need to do some effort yourself first

Answer (score 0):

1. check your input value datatype and prevent input string or value to
   cause crash your formula like division by zero
2. change  your for loop index from value to less tan a value

   for (int i =0 ; i<10)
3. and keep your code in try catch block and pass exception parameter
   to see  your error.

   ```
   try
   {
       n1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
       n2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text);
       n3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text);
       f(0) = xinitialization-1;

       for (x_NEWTON = 0; x1 >= 0; x_NEWTON++)
       {
           x1 = n1 * Math.Pow(x_NEWTON, 2) + n2 * x_NEWTON + n3;
           Initialization = x1 - 1;
       }

           approx1 = Initialization - ((n1*Math.Pow(Initialization,2)+n2*Initialization+n3) / (n1*2*Initialization-n2));
       approx2 = approx1 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx1, 2) + n2 * approx1 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx1 - n2));
       approx3 = approx2 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx2, 2) + n2 * approx2 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx2 - n2));
       approx4 = approx3 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx3, 2) + n2 * approx3 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx3 - n2));
       approx5 = approx4 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx4, 2) + n2 * approx4 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx4 - n2));
       approx6 = approx5 - ((n1 * Math.Pow(approx5, 2) + n2 * approx5 + n3) / (n1 * 2 * approx5 - n2));

       Newton1.Text = ("" + approx6);
   }
   catch (exception ex)
   {
       messagebox.show(ex.message);
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Checking user input is good (even though you are not checking it in your code sample), but this is definitely not the reason of infinite loop. 2. what is _tan_ value? you mean ten? But there maybe more then ten iterations required? 3. Putting `try/catch` everywhere is bad.

Comment: Also, as for now this looks more like a comment, than an answer. Can you improve it?